# Inconveniente en sitio web responsive al querer rotar (cambiar de tamaño) la pantalla

Tags: jquery, css3, responsive, screen

Tengo un **sitio web responsive** y todo funciona perfecto en los diferentes dispositios y resoluciones de pantalla. El único inconveniente que vi recientemente fue cuando se me dio por rotar la pantalla de mi móvil mientras visualizaba el contenido de mi página. En ese momento no se redimensiono el contenido según la resolución (quedaba con la resolución anterior), lo cual  se veía medio feo. Lo único que puedo hacer es volver a recargar la página (con la resolución que se estaba viendo fea) y ahí sí que el contenido lo muestra de manera correcta.

En mi página externa de estilos *CSS* hago uso de **@media** según la resolución, pero se ve que no alcanza cuando se cambia el tamaño del dispositivo mientras se muestra el contenido. Están de la forma siguiente:
 `@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {…}
 @media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {…}`

He leído que una posible solución es hacer uso de **JQuery**, agregando la siguiente instrucción:

`$(window).resize(function(){ location.reload(); });`

El tema es que tengo muchas páginas internas y sólo la principal trabaja con **JQuery**. No quiero tener que agregar a cada página la llamada al archivo y la línea del script. Por eso quería saber si conocen otra alternativa que quizás se logre realizar desde la misma hoja de estilo (sería algo único y para todo el sitio). El tema es que claro, debo saber el evento que se ejecuta, para así refrescar la página y por eso sí o sí debo hacer uso de **JQuery**, pero bueno podría haber algo.

De todas formas, si conocen otra manera de poder evitar ese error (detalle mejor dicho) al rotar la página y sin tener que refrescar la página, mucho mejor.

Comment: Yo probaria agregarle la orientacion, algo asi: `@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (orientation : landscape) {…}`

Comment: Eso no ha funcionado para mí. Es lo mismo que antes. Al parecer voy a tener que hacer uso de **JQuery** en cada uno de mis páginas.